# match logstring with regex

Tags: regex, monaco-editor

Hopefully I find help here, cause I really don't have a clue about regex. I'm trying to create a logfile viewer with the [monaco editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-custom-languages) I started from this sample but my logstrings can be multiline and I would like to use a different dateformat. So assuming I have a logstring like this:

```
[2017-02-03 22:07:56] [info] [Memory] After GC, total memory:737mb, used: 268mb, reclaimed: 293
[2017-02-03 22:10:15] [info] [Memory] After GC, total memory:705mb, used: 247mb, reclaimed: 141
[2017-02-03 22:10:25] [info] [Memory] After GC, total memory:705mb, used: 258mb, reclaimed: 21
[2017-02-03 22:14:34] [warn] [Evaluator] org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: Cannot convert null to an object.
   Caused by error in Business Rule: 'GlobalHideGlobalUsersFromNonAdmins' at line 5

      2: 
      3:    var encodedQueryString = 'sys_domain!=global';
      4:    
==>   5:    var imp = gs.getImpersonatingUserName().toString();
      6:    if(imp.length > 0) {
      7:        encodedQueryString = encodedQueryString + '^ORuser_name=' + imp;
      8:    }

[2017-02-03 22:14:34] [warn] [Evaluator] org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: Cannot convert null to an object.
   Caused by error in Business Rule: 'GlobalHideGlobalUsersFromNonAdmins' at line 1

==>   1: (function executeRule(current, previous /*null when async*/) {
      2: 
      3:    var encodedQueryString = 'sys_domain!=global';
      4:
```

This currently doesn't match my dateformat and it will only match the first line of a logmessage if there are carriage returns it doesn't match to the next logmessage. Any RegexGuru here that could help me out? :)

```
monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider('log', {
  tokenizer: {
    root: [
      [/\[error.*/, "custom-error"],
      [/\[warn.*/, "custom-warn"],
      [/\[info.*/, "custom-info"],
      [/\[debug.*/, "custom-debug"],
      [/\[[a-zA-Z 0-9:]+\]/, "custom-date"],
    ]
  }
});
```

**UPDATE:**
So here is the solution I've come up with. Apparently I'm still not able to match multiple lines between to [DATE] Strings. So for now I will just match e.g. [error] as a workaround. Maybe somebody can push me in the right direction...

```
monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider('log', {
  tokenizer: {
    root: [
      [/\[error\]/, "custom-error"],
      [/\[warn\]/, "custom-warn"],
      [/\[info\]/, "custom-info"],
      [/\[debug\]/, "custom-debug"],
      [/^\[\d{4}[./-]\d{2}[./-]\d{2} \d{2}[./:]\d{2}[./:]\d{2}]/, "custom-date"],
    ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be missing an escape at the end of the pattern in your update - should be "]" for the closing bracket.

Here's a tighter pattern, extracting on what the subgroups of digits all share:

```
\[(\d{2,4}[\:\-\s\]])+
```

Could you give an example of what you want to capture in cases of "multiple lines between two [DATE] strings"?

Hope this helps!